# i/o failure connecting to parse server from android studio API 28

Tags: java, android, parse-server

My **AndroidManifest.xml**    file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.parse.starter"
    android:targetSandboxVersion="1">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:name=".StarterApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:name=".UserListActivity"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My **network_security_config** file has

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">server.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

And I am using  `compilerSdkVersion 28`  ,     `minSdkVersion 26` , `targetSdkVersion 28` , `gradle build 4.0.1`

Still it can't connect to parse server. I even tried with only `http` as well as `https`. I don't know what to do. Whenever I am trying to connect to parse server it's showing a `Toast` of `i/o failure`.
Please help as soon as possible.

Comment: can you add the error android studio is giving you please, I am not sure to understand your error

Answer (score 0):

Change your xml/security_network_config like this, because it's work for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>
</base-config>
</network-security-config>
```